# Get Country and Region from Longitude and Latitude without using a webservice

Tags: location, ip, coordinate

Is there a database that I can use to convert longitude and latitude to a country and region. I do not want to use a web service because I will have lots of coordinates to convert.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this website : http://www.boutell.com/zipcodes/

This link provides an archive .zip which contains a CSV file that allow us to search U.S cities by latitude/longitude. I think it will be difficult to find a similar data source for all countries around the world without using webservices.

Otherwise, have try to use a webservice in a script ? That is the only way to verify if it's feasible or not in terms of data volume and there is probably a way to parallelize these treatments if it's necessary.